# How to run socketio server properly on multiple cores using cluster module of NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis, node-cluster

Socket IO server is running fine on single instance of NodeJs. But when I'm using cluster module of NodeJS to run the servers on multiple cores I'm getting the error, "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response". I've googled the reason and found out that,

> Essence of the problem is, when you run multiple Node app threads (workers) on a server, or multiple servers, socket.io clients connections are routed by cluster in a random round-robin manner, and handshaken / authorized io client requests get handed to workers where they are not handshaken / authorized, where the mess begins.  [Source Link](http://www.farennikov.com/2013/06/scaling-socket-io-with-node-js-cluster/)

I've tried a couple of things to make it work but no success so far. Here's the code

```
'use strict';

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var cluster = require('cluster');
var domain = require('domain');
var socketIo = require('./config/socketio');
var REDIS = require('redis')

var store = REDIS.createClient();
var pub = REDIS.createClient();
var sub = REDIS.createClient();


if(cluster.isMaster) {
    var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;

for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
}

} else {
    var d = domain.create ();
    d.on ("error", function (error){
     // start new server
    });

// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = require('http');

  d.run (function (){
    server = server.createServer(app);
  });

require('./config/express')(app);
require('./config/redis')();
require('./routes')(app);

server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
});


var redis = require('socket.io-redis');

var socketIO = require('socket.io')(server, {
  serveClient: (config.env === 'production') ? false : true,
  path: '/socket.io-client'
});

sub.subscribe('chat');
socketIO.adapter(redis( {host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));
socketIo.createSocketConnection('/dummy', socketIO, sub, pub, store);

exports = module.exports = app;
}
```

File: ./config/socketio

```
'use strict';

function addNamespaceForId (socketio, namespace, sub, pub, store){

    socketio.of(namespace).on('connection', function(socket) {

        onConnect(socketio, socket, namespace, sub, pub, store);

        console.info('[%s] CONNECTED', socket.address);

         sub.on('message', function(pattern, key){
             store.hgetall(key, function(e, obj){
                 socket.send(obj.uid + ": " + obj.text)
            })
        })


        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.info('[%s] DISCONNECTED', socket.address);
        });
    });
}
}


function onConnect(io, socket, namespace, sub, pub, store) {
socket.on('message', function(from, msg) {

    store.incr("messageNextId", function(e, id){
        store.hmset("messages:" + id, { uid: socket.sessionId, text: 'text;'     }, function(e, r){
            pub.publish("chat", "messages:" + id)
        })
    })

    io.emit('broadcast', {
        payload : from['message'],
        source : from
    });
    io.of(namespace).emit('broadcast', {
        payload : from['message'],
        source : from
    });
});

// When the client emits 'info', this listens and executes
socket.on('info', function(data) {
    console.info('[%s] %s', socket.address, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});

// Insert sockets below
require('../api/thing/thing.socket').register(socket);
}

module.exports = {
    createSocketConnection : function (namespace, socketio, sub, pub, store){
    addNamespaceForId(socketio, namespace, sub, pub, store);
    }
};
```

I've also tried using adapter for redis as suggested in the [documentation.](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/)

This setup works sometimes but not always. I'm unable to figure out the missing point.

Comment: The part you left out of your yellow highlight was this: "This happens if socket.io sockets created by workers use memory store and do not share transports between each other, or in other words, are not scale ready."

Comment: Per [this page on Using multiple nodes with socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/), you have to implement some sort of [sticky session clustering](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) so that a given client is consistently connected to the same node process.  Express session is memory based and will not work across multiple processes.

Comment: @jfriend00 sticky session works based on ip but what will happen if there are multiple users which needs to be assigned to separate chat rooms and they all are working behind a big corporate ip ?

Comment: @dark_shadow - With a proper implementation, there is no connection between what server a connection is assigned to and what chat room they are in.   Chat rooms can include users from all the servers.  From a given server, you can be in any chat room so the IP-based sticky session should not be an issue.